# How to crop image that is a byte array

Tags: c#, .net, azure, image-processing, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function and would want to crop an image that is inside a byte array, and then save it to a blob. I am not sure how to do the cropping part, because Bitmap is not available in Azure Functions. Here is my saving to blob:

```
private async static Task<string> CreateBlob(string name, byte[] data, TraceWriter log)
```

which works fine for what it does. Also, I have the URL of the image I want to crop, if that helps. Just don't know how to achieve this with an Azure Function. Any ideas?

EDIT

[image: original image]

this is the original image, that I have inside a byte array. I want to crop another one from it with the size - 650x290

```
int cropStartX = 0;
int cropStartY = 0;
int cropWidth = 650;
int cropHeight = 290;
int multiply = cropWidth * cropHeight;

byte[] croppedImage = new byte[multiply];

for (int j = cropStartX; j < cropStartX + cropWidth; j++)
{
    for (int k = cropStartY; k < cropStartY + cropHeight; k++)
    {
        if ((j + k * cropWidth) >= ((byte[])OriginalPic).Length)
            break;

        croppedImage[j + k * cropWidth] = ((byte[])OriginalPic)[j + k * cropWidth];
        }
    }
```

This is the size of the OriginalPic - byte[49121]

This is the output if I set:

```
croppedImage[j + k * cropWidth] = ((byte[])OriginalPic)[j + k * (cropWidth + 20)];
```

[image: cropped image]

Comment: If the image is inside a byte array... is there a reason you can not just index through and copy over what you need?

Comment: Is this possible? I need to crop a number of small pictures out of it and I know the specific coordinates and size of them. It would be great if I can have them in several byte arrays each, this would be the perfect case, but I don't know how to manipulate the byte array to get the small pictures. Any ideas?

Comment: one dimensional byte array?

Comment: Yes, that's all. But I am worried that it is an Azure Function, if that matters.. I would really appreciate a method to which I can just provide the byte array with some coordinates and size and it returns another byte array. That's what I am looking for, but it seems that is is not possible

Comment: You would most likely need an image manipulation library. Images come in many formats (bits per pixel, byte order, pallet/direct, etc.) and encodings (compress/raw). Any image manipulation library should be able to export an image to a raw byte array.

Comment: Was looking for a Nuget package for image manipulation that works with Azure Functions, but I am out of luck

Comment: idk what Azure Function is, but to make sure I understand, you can queiry single data items out of its byte array ie var x = byteArray[5]?

Comment: There is a mismatch between the cropped size you are describing and the initial picture size: to fill the cropping size you are describing would require that the main picture have at least (650x290) = 188500px... but it only contains 49121 px. (assuming 1px is equivalent to 1 byte)

Comment: After downloading the image, it appears to have dimensions of 1024 x 434.  which should contain 444416 px... so I am not sure what your original image byte array represents (49121).

Comment: As far as that crazy data, I believe that is just uninitialized memory.  I am pretty sure that if you initialized the cropped byte array to zeros that would all clean up to black.  Basically, your if statement is protecting from out of bounds (which you leave rather quickly), leaving the rest of that array which you later declare to the program is an image in whatever state it was prior to your initialization of the array

Comment: Your image data is compressed and can not be cropped on a byte index lookup.

Comment: If you can get your image to a raw byte array through decompression as noted by glenebob, then you will be able to apply the method that I stated.

Answer (score 0):

idk if this is what you are after, but assuming you know the dimensions of your picture, you just have to encode that into your index :

*pseudocode*

```
int cropWidth = 100;
int cropHeight = 50;
byte[cropWidth*cropHeight] croppedImage;
for(int i=cropStartX;i<cropStartX+cropWidth;i++)
{
    for(int ii = cropStartY;ii<cropStartY+cropHeight;ii++)
    {
        croppedImage[i + ii*cropWidth] = image[i + ii*mainImageWidth];
    }
}
```

I know this isnt as fast as if you can actually just do a memory copy function... but will do what you need.

---

Update: after looking at more of your information I am afraid that this method will not work for you as you have compressed image data.  Basically jpeg compresses data at a size of about 1:10 which makes more sense now that your image byte array is only 49k as that is almost exactly the file size, which contains jpeg compressed information for a 1024x434 picture of rgb.  Long story short you can not simply query pixel locations from that array to get meaningful data unless you were to uncompressed the image prior to cropping.  Apologies as I should have seen this as soon as I noticed a "byte" was supposedly representing an rgb pixel (which does not match).

Comment: note that you may need some shifts (ie + or - 1) in a couple of those lines depending specifics of the image and language.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am looking for but it crashes with an exception "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: Yup, that is what I was talking about with the index shift.  If you post more code with dimensions of the image and stuff I may be able to help you debug.  But just running through with breakpoints and checking your indicies should get you there.

Comment: Another great way for debugging this type of thing is making markers ie instead of cropping out the image u want, just make a copy of the original image with those targetted pixels colored so that you can see if they are shifting or not where you expect them to be.

Comment: I use the code you provided, but I would usually want the width of the cropped image to be the same as the original so I guess "mainImageWidth" should be the same as "cropWidth"?

Comment: posting your code is gonna make this way easier to debug, but try to find out if you are missing by a little or a lot (ie where are u in your for loops when you go out of bounds, is it in the middle or right at the end)

Comment: Just put an if clause and it doesn't crash, but now it does nothing at all. The image is not cropped, maybe it's something with the algorithm

Comment: Print out the j and k values on that if statement failing, also what is the size of the main image array (and the image dimensions)

Comment: Just updated the question with all things you required. It's not failing anymore after the if-clause but does nothing unfortunately too

Comment: two posibilities: (make sure that data transfer is taking place, to do that, print out or breakpoint the value being read from the image into a local variable prior to being inserted into your cropped array) (bounds are way off and if statement is just stabilizing, put a print statement that outputs the j and k values when that break is hit